# Improving performance when sending message using asynchronous delivery

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

IBM provides [a method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html#setMsgBatchSize(int)) to control performance when using asynchronous delivery:

> setMsgBatchSize
>
> public void setMsgBatchSize(int size)
> throws javax.jms.JMSException
>
> Sets the message batch size.
>
> Parameters:
> size - the maximum number of messages to be taken at once when using asynchronous delivery.
> Throws:
> javax.jms.JMSException

How can we achieve this on ActiveMQ? From the official documentation of ActiveMQ they have provided property named:

```
cf.setUseAsyncSend(true);
```

I'm not sure if ActiveMQ was setting `msg batch size` by default, and when we set `useAsyncSend` to `true` we can achieve results as IBM did.

Thank you in advance and willing to listen to any discussion.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ does not have an equivalent option.  When a message is sent it is immediately put to the wire and if the async send option is enabled (default is true) then for messages that are not persistent or are within a transaction there is no wait for remote acknowledgement of the send, your code can immediately send the next message.